# Populate an ItemSetCollection with String Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C#. I know how to individually add an item to the itemsetcollection. My code is:

```
ItemsetCollection db;
string item1 = "word1";
string item2 = "word2";

db = new ItemsetCollection();
db.Add(new Itemset() {item1,item2});
```

The problem is I have an array of type string populated with a listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
{
    array[i] = list.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

I want to add my array items to the itemsetcollection:

```
db = new ItemsetCollection();
db.Add(new Itemset() array); //here i need to add my array
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to add the array as a whole to the Itemset, or each element of the array to the Itemset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsetCollection is not a standard .NET framework class.  I assume that your ItemsetCollection class inherits from `Collection`.  If so, you can use the standard implementation of `Add` or override it and create your own implementation.

As for your code, `db.Add(new Itemset() array)` isn't good syntax.  Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
db = new ItemsetCollection();
var itemSet = new Itemset() {item1,item2};

for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
{
    itemSet.Add(list.Items[i].ToString());
}

db.Add(itemSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

drop the `new`. it already exists!

```
 db = new ItemsetCollection();
 db.Add(array);
```

if it didn't work, you should cast it to `Itemset` somehow!

```
 db = new ItemsetCollection();
 db.Add((Itemset())array);
```

or

```
 db = new ItemsetCollection();
 db.Add(array.toItemset);
```

if the method exists!